# deserialize JSON without one by one

Tags: json, vb.net

I have this JSON:

> {"JOE":"0.90000000","BILL":"3.30000000","MONROE":"1.20000000"}

when i do a paste especial in VB.NET, this was created:

```
Public Class Rootobject
    Public Property JOE As String
    Public Property BILL As String
    Public Property MONROE As String
End class
```

With 3 elements, it can be handled, but with 200, no.
i need the way to declare the JSON data in order to access with a

```
for each in 
next
```

and look in any iteraction for each name and value couple of data with an index.

what is the right definition for JSON and what is the code for deserialize and get all the data?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Where did that JSON come from?  its rather messed up.  Presumably `Joe` is a property value not a property name, and the values arent in your class as values; `JOE` will be `"0.90000000"`, and finally it isnt really a collection that can be iterated.  That said you could deserialize to a dictionary but that wont work if there are any names repeasted

Comment: Note that the answer you got on your last question -- after you changed the question entirely -- showed  how to use a converter to create a collection of Name-Value pairs from data very much like this.  This JSON is a bit more messed up though; the other one at least had the data as a collection - this one either does not or you edited out important key parts of the JSON so that no answer will work with the real data.

Comment: As others pointed out, thats not going to work. Although the json you post may not be correct you could write a function to parse that, rather easily into class objects...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
var dict = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Dictionary<string, string>>(json);
```

**UPDATE:**

Just realized that you want it in VB.NET

```
Dim j1 As String = "{ ""JOE"":""0.90000000"",""JOE"":""3.30000000"",""MONROE"":""1.20000000""}"
Dim dict = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(Of Dictionary(Of String, String))(j1)
For Each kvp In dict
    Console.WriteLine(kvp.Key & " - " + kvp.Value)
Next
```

working sample at https://dotnetfiddle.net/YrLuyX

PS: JSON.NET handles duplicate as well.

Comment: what can be the definition class for it?

Comment: `Dictionary(Of String, string)` means there is **not** a class - and as mentioned this will fail if the real JSON has duplicate keys/names @SomeOneMore

Comment: works perfectly. thanks. thanks for your very helpful response. other people only give lot of theorical but nothing about solutions. there is the difference between the problems theorical discuss and the real problems solutions. Thanks!

Comment: can you please tell me how to do with this? {"JOE":{"id":7,"age":"23"},"BILLY":{"id":8,"age":"29"}} in order to get the id and age? the number of persons is unknow; can be 2, can be 100.